# Woocommerce phone number input filed from right to left

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, right-to-left

Can I change input text for phone to be from right to left

[image]

I tried to customize CSS with that rules:

```
form.checkout #billing_phone_field label,
 form.checkout #shipping_phone_field label {
margin-right: 260px;
}
```

This css code changes the label from right to left not the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the **CSS direction property** to set the text direction to "right-to-left":

```
form.checkout #billing_phone_field label,
form.checkout #shipping_phone_field label {
     direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: can i move the input text and placeholder not the main title

Comment: sure, target the input as `form.checkout #billing_phone_field input`

Comment: thank you very much it work form me, what about if moving the input  like to center or  20xp from the flag etc

Comment: please let's focus on the original question and feel free to post a new one.

Comment: and please don't forget to valid the answer, it can help others, thanks.